# Reload the "Sign In With Google" button if user changes locale

Tags: google-signin

I can't find any documented way to reload the new "Sign in With Google" button in JavaScript.

I have to remove the script tag and the "button" div then re-add them both.

Does anyone know of a better way to do this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Have you looked at the JS [`renderButton`](https://developers.google.com/identity/gsi/web/reference/js-reference#google.accounts.id.renderButton) method ?

Assuming you have something like this to initialize the library and display the button in JS, you might be able to update locale in the second parameter to renderButton and call the method again to switch languages.

```
<html>
  <body>
      <script src="https://accounts.google.com/gsi/client" async defer></script>
      <script>
        function handleCredentialResponse(response) {
          console.log("Encoded JWT ID token: " + response.credential);
        }
        window.onload = function () {
          google.accounts.id.initialize({
            client_id: "YOUR_GOOGLE_CLIENT_ID",
            callback: handleCredentialResponse
          });
          google.accounts.id.renderButton(
            document.getElementById("buttonDiv"),
            { theme: "outline", size: "large", locale: "the new locale" }
          );
          google.accounts.id.prompt(); // also display the One Tap dialog
        }
    </script>
    <div id="buttonDiv"></div>
    </div>
  </body>
</html>
```

Obviously, you'd call `renderButton` a second time from outside of the window.onload example above, I didn't go as far as showing that in the code sample though.

Comment: Thanks! - That looks promising - I'll investigate that route!  Just seen the link - I couldn't find that client reference anywhere!